# Why is my jump boost gamepass in roblox not working?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I decided to make a jump boost gamepass in roblox but when I test and I have my gamepass it doesn't work.

here is my code

```
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local PlayerUserID = Players.LocalPlayer.UserId

print(PlayerUserID)
Players.LocalPlayer.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
    print(MarketplaceService:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(PlayerUserID, 21723718))
    if MarketplaceService:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(PlayerUserID, 21723718) then
        char.Humanoid.UseJumpPower = true
        char.Humanoid.JumpPower = 100
    end
end)
```

it is a server script on ServerScriptService

I cant see any output that comes from the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server script is targeting an object that doesn't exist. `game.Players.LocalPlayer` is only defined in localscripts.

To get around this, use `Players.PlayerAdded`

Use this code instead

```
local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    plr.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        if MarketplaceService:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(PlayerUserID, 21723718) then
            char.Humanoid.UseJumpPower = true
            char.Humanoid.JumpPower = 100
        end
    end)
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use LocalPlayer in a Server Script. You will have to get the player via other methods.

Check out [the Roblox gamepass guide](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Game-Passes-One-Time-Purchases).